# Windows 10 built-in apps not there for just one user

Tags: windows-10

1 user logged in to a computer and Calculator and Sticky Notes are missing.

I looked in Settings->Apps, tried the Microsoft Store and both apps are just not there. So I logged in to the same computer and both apps ARE there. Off to the 'net I went to search for answers and thought this one would help but didn't:

```
Get-AppxPackage -allusers | foreach {Add-AppxPackage -register “$($_.InstallLocation)\appxmanifest.xml” -DisableDevelopmentMode}
```

It is so strange.  My last resort would be to backup the user's data, delete the local profile and start with a new one.

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Is the user the built-in Administrator by chance?

Comment: The user was not a local admin at first.  I added it as a local admin during troubleshooting, but didn't get any farther.

Comment: I didn’t ask if the user was a local administrator I asked if they were the built-in Administrator that typically cannot use the Windows Store since it can’t be linked to a Microsoft Account

Comment: Sorry, I was not wearing my glasses earlier.  The user is not a local admin.  I just found out something else: the user is logged on with a roaming profile.

This user used to login on a WYSE terminal and is now using a regular desktop computer.  I'm almost certain now that the profile is corrupted somehow.

Comment: You should try deleting the profile.  If the working profiles are not roaming, change the roaming profile, to a regular profile.